# I need to format the email sent from my Windows Form C# application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

When a user clicks "email" button it sends everything in my form. I need to add bold and italic to the form. here is the button click code:

*For those looking to use this code, I have placed everything that will need changed in all caps, any questions on the code please ask.

Here is the code behind:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); 
            msg.To.Add("SENT FROM EMAIL");               
            MailAddress address = new MailAddress("WHO THE FORM GETS EMAIL   
 FROM");
            msg.From = address;            
            msg.Subject = "Daily Checklist for " + check_Date_TextBox.Text;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

I want to format this line

```
msg.Body = "Check Date: " + <b>check_Date_TextBox.Text</b> + Environment.NewLine +
```

It has been recomdnded to put the html formatting in the code above but it gives me an error

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTP CLIENT, PORT);
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;   
        client.EnableSsl = false;                               
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("SENT FROM 
EMAIL", "PASSWORD");
            client.Credentials = credentials;


            client.Send(msg);
        }
```

Comment: You need to use HTML.

Comment: What formatting does your email system accept? (It is probably HTML).

Comment: Yes HTML, can someone please instruct me how to incorporate into this code?

Comment: Please consider providing small nice looking sample instead of wall of code.

Comment: 1) please simplify your example. 2) turn on the HTML flag and format the email in html 3) beware that there is no standard for html in email.

Comment: [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your friend, Check it!

Comment: I have simplified my code, apologies for the wall of code!

Comment: You have quotes in random places. Please clean your code up as best you can. If you can't get it to compile, then update your question to show where the compilation error is and what it's saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string body you are creating give the html tags such as `<b>, <i>` where ever you needed and before sending add the below code also

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

hope it will help

Comment: I have updated the code above to show the issue, thanks again for all the help!

Comment: `msg.Body = "Check Date: <b>" + check_Date_TextBox.Text + "</b>"` try this..what error r u getting there

Comment: This sends thru the email <b>5/1/2015</b>  when 5/1/2015 is entered into the textbox

Comment: Nevermind i did not have the msg.IsBodyHtml = true; at the top. This worked thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to here it is working..also you can use stringbuilder also for including htmlcodes `StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
mailBody.AppendFormat("<h1>Heading Here</h1>");`